# Is it appropriate to multiply a matrix directly with a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Reading some math papers online I came across a curious notation I have never seen before...

Let $\mathcal{A} = image(A)$, then we can take a matrix $B$ and multiply $\mathcal{A}$ to have $B \mathcal{A}$

Is this a conventional practice in (higher) linear algebra?? Also, in what situations might this be useful?

Comment: This is very common in mathematics.  One version of it follows: let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a function and $A\subseteq X$.  One often defines $f(A)=\{f(a):a\in A\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually $B\mathcal{A}$ indicates the image of a set $\mathcal{A}$ through the linear function $B$. Suppose $V,W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces and that $B:V\rightarrow W$. In this case,

$$B\mathcal{A}=\{w\in W : \exists v \in \mathcal{A} :w=Bv\}=\{Bv:v\in V\}$$

This is the set of vectors of $w$ which can be obtained applying the linear functional $B$ to some vector in the set $\mathcal{A}$.

This is of crucial importance in higher linear algebra: for instance, an operator $\phi$ is said to be $U$-stable for some subspace $U \leq V$ if $\phi(U)\subseteq U$, i.e. if the restriction $\phi_{|U}$ is a linear operator on $U$ regarded as a vector space. You will hear about this again if you get into Jordan theory, which generalizes the concept of eigenvectors/eigenvalues and of diagonalization.

Answer (score 2):

It's commonly understood that $f(X)$ is the image of $X$ (where $X$ is a subset of $f$s domain). This is just an extension of this principle.

But there's another interesting part here since $\mathcal A$ may be represented by the vectors spanning the subspace in which case it would be a normal matrix multiplication again (and the result is a matrix consisting of vectors spanning the image of $\mathcal A$).

Comment: +1 For the comment about only needing to consider a spanning set.